# Is there a trigger to detect a spreadsheet name change in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to detect when the user changes the name of the `spreadsheet` (not the sheet).

Of the triggers, the `timeBased` and `onChange` are the most likely to be the solution. I would prefer not to use `timeBased` as the max frequency you can use is once per hour (in an addon, which is my situation) and my use case is to update the database right after the `spreadsheet` name is updated.

`onChange` is a bit confusing, there is a `changeType` called `OTHER` that may work but there is no explanation of what events this triggers on. 
Is there a list of events that trigger `OTHER`  anywhere? 
Would this work for a `spreadsheet` name change?

Is there another solution I haven't found yet?

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? ``the name of the spreadsheet`` in your question is the filename of Spreadsheet or the sheet name of each sheet in Spreadsheet? For the former and latter, OnChange event trigger cannot be used and can be used, respectively. If the latter, when OnChange trigger is fired, how about checking the sheet name of all sheets? By this, I think that you can detect whether the sheet name was changed. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike so I'm not referring the the sheet names. I'm talking about the spreadsheet name which is on the top left of the UI, which yes is also the filename. How are you sure that onChange cannot be used for checking this? I can't find google documentation to say it can or cannot work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my comment was not useful for your situation. This is due to my poor skill. About ``How are you sure that onChange cannot be used for checking this?``, when I tested this situation, the OnChange event trigger was not fired. When you tested this, what result did you get?

Comment: @Tanaike I haven't actually tested it yet, because to test an installable trigger you have to publish (can be unlisted) the add on. I was hoping to get some actual documentation clearly stating the facts before moving forward. But your experience mirrors what I've read from a couple others so I think it is not possible with onChange..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing this with the onChange trigger, I've verified that it does not fire when changing the spreadsheet name.

[I've created this feature request with google, hopefully they will add this event to a trigger or create a new one](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134743883)

Currently there is no way to capture the spreadsheet name change, you have to go about it by checking the name during onOpen, onEdit, onChange trigger events. Not ideal at all and leaves the potential for the name change to not be captured by the add on/apps script code for some time if ever.

Answer (score 0):

Since your using an add-on, your best option might be the [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) function. It won't trigger when the name is changed, but will when the spreadsheet is open. This might be a good compromise from the time trigger.

Comment: Updating the spreadsheet name with onEdit, onOpen or timeBased are all options but none will catch the update as it occurs. I'm already using onEdit so I may stick with that.